# Raw types and type safety

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion

So, let's say i have a simple list if Integers:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
// intList.add("zxc"); // this will obviously fail
```

Now let's wrap the list inside another list:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfInt = new ArrayList<>();
listOfListOfInt.add(intList);
```

It's all fine. Now let's create the method

```
private static void method1(List<? extends List> cont) { // [1]
    List<? super Date> data = cont.get(0);  // [2]
    data.add(new Date());
}
```

Basically i'm adding DATE to the first list in the list, because i'm telling it to treat that list as `List<? super Date>`.
And it works because of the type erasure, of course:

```
    method1(listOfListOfInt);
    System.out.println(intList);
```

prints `[1, 2, Tue Jun 14 23:41:15 BST 2016]`, so my `List<Integer>` now has a Date in it.

Now i understand what's going on, because of the type erasure the `List<? extends List>` becomes just a List, and then it's up to me what to put in it, so i'm putting Date.

Now the question i don't quite understand is that why there is no warning of "Unchecked assignment/calls" at all? According to the java compiler that code is perfectly type safe?

It will give the warning if in the method1 you'll replace `List<? extends List>` to just a `List<List>` for example, or if you'll replace `List<? super Date>` with just a `List`, and so on, generally you'll be warned about unchecked assignments/calls. But in this case you won't, all is fine.

UPDATE: Apparently there's warning by the compiler, but Intellij Idea refuses to show it for some reason. I have "Unchecked warning" inspection set without ignoring anything. And all settings are defaults anyway i think.

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 Build #IC-145.1617, built on June 3, 2016 JRE:
>   1.8.0_77-b03 x86 JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Update2: it's not a duplicate, as the question is not about the functionality of raw types but about the lack of warning in this particular case. And it turns out it's just an IDE quirk.

Comment: I get a warning. How do you compile your code?

Comment: This has to do with backward compatibility more than erasure. Why is it easy to blame erasure for everything?

Comment: Your problem is that the second `List` in the type `List<? extends List>` is *raw*. Raw is not the same as *erasure*. Raw loses type safety, erasure doesn't. Your IDE(!) should have warned you about the raw use of a generic.

Comment: I'm not "blaming" type erasure, it's working as expected. I'm just puzzled that there are no warnings in this case.

Comment: So where's warning that i'm converting generic type into the raw type then? Note that it GIVES a warning if instead of `List<? extends List>` you're using slightly different RAW type `<List<List>>`.

Comment: It should be `List<? extends List<Integer>> cont`; no converting here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the use of a **raw** type in this declaration: `List<? extends List>`. The second `List` is *raw*. Your issue has nothing to do with *type erasure*.

When entering the following code in Eclipse, I get warnings.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        intList.add(1);
        intList.add(2);
        List<List<Integer>> listOfListOfInt = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfListOfInt.add(intList);
        method1(listOfListOfInt);
        System.out.println(listOfListOfInt);
    }
    private static void method1(List<? extends List> cont) { // [1]
        List<? super Date> data = cont.get(0);  // [2]
        data.add(new Date());
    }
}
```

*Warnings from Eclipse*

```
[1] List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
[2] Type safety: The expression of type capture#1-of ? extends List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<? super Date>
```

When compiling with `jdk1.8.0_91`, I get:

```
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Adding `-Xlint:unchecked`, I get:

```
Test.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
                List<? super Date> data = cont.get(0);  // [2]
                                                  ^
  required: List<? super Date>
  found:    CAP#1
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends List from capture of ? extends List
1 warning
```

As you can see, **you have been warned**, both by the IDE (Eclipse in my case) and by the Java compiler.

Comment: Intellij Idea doesn't give me any warning in this case, but you're right - i've just tried to compile it manually and it does have the warning which makes sense. So i guess some obscure flag somewhere in settings for Idea is unset, although i can't find where. It's very weird.